# Output all values of a yaml file key with formatting

Tags: ruby, yaml, multiple-value

I have a yaml file that has multiple values for a couple of keys:

```
inbox:
  mary:
          - '-MD-C-LAUREL-ADMIN'
          - '-MD-E-BALTIMORE-ADMIN'
          - '-MD-R1-CAMBRIDGE-ADMIN'
          - '-MD-R2-BELAIR-ADMIN'
          - '-MD-R4-LAUREL-ADMIN'
          - '-MD-R5-HAGERSTWN-ADMIN'
  mike:
          - '-VA-E-Richmond-Admin'
          - '-VA-Richmond-Admin'
          - '-VA-Manassas-Admin'
          - '-VA-Norfolk-Admin'
          - '-VA-Roanoke-Admin'
          - '-VA-Verona-Admin'
  max: '-ATLANTA-RO-ADMIN'
```

YAML file 'test.yml'

```
POC = YAML.load_file('test.yml')    

def get_info(name)
  POC['inbox'][name.downcase].nil? ? "** #{name} IS NOT POC **" : POC['inbox'][name.downcase]
end
```

What I want to do is output all those keys with some sort of formatting, for example when this is run:

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> POC = YAML.load_file('test.yml')
=> {"inbox"=>{"mary"=>["-MD-C-LAUREL-ADMIN", "-MD-E-BALTIMORE-ADMIN", "-MD-R1-CAMBRIDG
E-ADMIN", "-MD-R2-BELAIR-ADMIN", "-MD-R4-LAUREL-ADMIN", "-MD-R5-HAGERSTWN-ADMIN"], "mi
ke"=>["-VA-E-Richmond-Admin", "-VA-Richmond-Admin", "-VA-Manassas-Admin", "-VA-Norfolk
-Admin", "-VA-Roanoke-Admin", "-VA-Verona-Admin"]}}
irb(main):005:0>     def get_info(name)
< "** #{name} IS NOT POC **" : POC['inbox'][name.downcase]
irb(main):007:1>     end
=> :get_info
irb(main):008:0> get_info('mary')
=> ["-MD-C-LAUREL-ADMIN", "-MD-E-BALTIMORE-ADMIN", "-MD-R1-CAMBRIDGE-ADMIN", "-MD-R2-B
ELAIR-ADMIN", "-MD-R4-LAUREL-ADMIN", "-MD-R5-HAGERSTWN-ADMIN"]
irb(main):009:0>
```

The expected output of this would be:

```
Possibly one of the following inboxes: 
1. -MD-C-LAUREL-ADMIN
2. -MD-E-BALTIMORE-ADMIN
3. -MD-R1-CAMBRIDGE-ADMIN
4. -MD-R2-BELAIR-ADMIN
5. -MD-R4-LAUREL-ADMIN
6. -MD-R5-HAGERSTWN-ADMIN
```

How can I go about outputting the information inside the array with numbers to match IF there is more than one value?

Comment: It really helps us if you'll strip the IRB output to only show the expressions and their output, not the IRB prompts. A lot of us use "Seeing Is Believing" in our editors, which makes it really easy to selectively show IRB-like output, without the noise. Keeping the code clean helps us help you.

Comment: @theTinMan Will do from now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with YAML at all. It's all about how to print out an array with index.

```
%w(foo bar baz).each.with_index(1) do |str, i|
  puts "#{i}. #{str}"
end
```

or

```
puts %w(foo bar baz).each.with_index(1).map{|str, i| "#{i}. #{str}"}
```

Comment: How does it have nothing to do with YAML if it comes from a YAML file?

Comment: The array can come from anywhere. You have nothing wrong in parsing YAML.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Glad you like it :)

Comment: "How does it have nothing to do with YAML if it comes from a YAML file?" When asking/debugging, it's really important to look at the flow of the data through the program, and only tag/ask about the parts that directly affect the program and question. Just because YAML was used _somewhere_ doesn't mean it's implicated as part of the problem, just as the disk that held the file wasn't involved nor was the CPU. Instead, at the point of the problem/question the YAML has been parsed into an hash of hashes of arrays, and is no longer involved and we're only concerned about the HoHoA.